# is it possible to bit mask a char array

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, arrays

Let's say I have the following char array

```
 char array[32];
```

I want to use only the 10 most significant bits of this array as a hash value.

Is it possible to use bitwise operation on this char array?

If so, how should i do it?

Comment: Define "10 most significant bits".

Comment: That would depend on byte and bit order and what is stored in the array. You can definitely do bit operations on the individual characters of the array, but you need to define "10 most significant bits" to get specific help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your implementation has 8-bit `char`, and that you have a 256-bit number stored in big endian in this array, here how to access the 10 msb of the 256-bit number.

```
uint16_t a;
a = (array[0] << 2 | (array[1] & 0xC0) >> 6) & 0x3FF;
```

Comment: Correct idea, bad implementation. Should be `(array[0]<<2) | ((array[1]>>6) & 0x3)`

Comment: @ugoren I don't agree. `((array[1]>>6) & 0x3)` is OK but is just an other alternative to `(array[1] & 0xC0) >> 6)`. And of course in both solutions you need the `& 0x3FF` at the end because of possible sign extension during `array[0]` `int` promotion.

Comment: now that you've fixed it, it's the same as my code. The `&0xc0` is meaningless, since the low bits are removed in the shift anyway.

Comment: @ugoren: I would have to agree with ouah.  It would appear that the bitwise operations you suggest using, perform the exact same function and would take the same amount of cycles.  Maybe you are taking something into account that I am missing.  If so, please let me know.

Comment: @ugoren I'm sorry but I didn't change *anything* after your comment.  And the `& 0xC0` is not meaningless in my code because without it, a sign extension on the `array[1]` during `int` promotion would change the final result.

Comment: @ouah, I wrote my first comment before you changed 0x3f to 0x3ff, and at the time your solution was obviously incorrect. Your current solution works only because of the implicit conversion to `int`, something I don't like relying on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want something like this (again assuming 8-bit `char`s stored big endian in `array`):

```
uint16_t a = (((uint16_t)array[0] & 0xFF) << 2 | ((uint16_t)array[1] & 0xFF) >> 6) & 0x3FF;
```

To break that down a bit:

```
uint16_t byte0 = (uint16_t)array[0] & 0xFF;
uint16_t byte1 = (uint16_t)array[1] & 0xFF;
uint16_t a = (byte0 << 2 | byte1 >> 6) & 0x3FF;
```

Comment: That appears to use 2 bits from `array[0]` and all the bits of `array[1]`.  Did you intend to make `array[1]` so significant?

Comment: Ugh totally right. The other way round I mean. Today not a good day!