# what is wrong with the following strtok() usage?

Tags: c, struct, runtime-error, strtok

I am using vc2010 and I am trying to read contents of a file into a struct as follows and it gives me run time error.

```
char buf[100];
char *token = NULL; 
while( fgets (buf , 100 , rd) != NULL )
{
    token = strtok( buf,", ");
    test_st.fp.chunk_offset = atol(token); 
    printf("\n %llu ", test_st.fp.chunk_offset); 

    //OPTION 1: if i do this there will be no runtime error but the same
    // value as the first token will be assigned to chunk_length
    token = strtok(buf, ",");
    //OPTION 2: this line gives error in the second while loop iteration
    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    test_st.fp.chunk_length = atol(token);
    printf("%llu ",  test_st.fp.chunk_length);  
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    ....
}
```

my other problem is how can i use strtok() or any- if there is one- to assign a very long character string(like the one after the second coma in the following file content) into a structure data member(in this case into **fp.fing_print**)?

Here is the first part of the file i am trying to read

```
0,4096,2ed692b40e335f7c20b71c5ed0486634
4096,3028,da40bf20c8ff189087b8bd7e8580118a
7124,2177,e6dfaee81e96095d302c82f9fd73dc55
9301,1128,76201eadff3c89a381a314ed311f75ff
```

the structure definition i am trying to read this into is:

```
typedef struct fpinfo
{
  unsigned long chunk_offset;
  unsigned long chunk_length;
  unsigned char fing_print[32];
}fpinfo;

typedef struct Hash_Entry {
   struct Hash_Entry *next;  /* Link entries within same bucket. */
   unsigned namehash;        /* hash value of key */
   struct fpinfo fp;
} Hash_Entry;
```

EDIT:
Yes you are right I have to use the second option.
I HAVE FOUND THE PROBLEM WITH THIS ONE. The file have empty lines between every line and it gives error message when it gets to these empty lines.

BUT I AM STUCK in the other problem where I have to read the last part of each line into the array member(**fp.fing_print**) of the structure.

Thank you everybody for your help!!!

EDIT:
the fing_print[32] array is supposed to hold 32 characters which are results of an md5 hash function. I am not sure if i have to make it a null terminated string or not. if you guys could give me a tip about it I will be more than grateful.

Comment: Your option 2 is the way to do it, passing NULL. Why are you passing a `'` instead of `,` for that one?

Comment: Are you checking that `strtok` isn't returning `NULL`? You'll be passing `NULL` to `atol` if that ever happens. I also don't understand why you're tokenizing on `'` rather than `,` for the line marked as `OPTION 2`.

Comment: @John: Does your actual code have that typo? If it does then that can be a reason why `strtok` returns `NULL` and you get an error. If not, you should be posting your actual code and not a rewrite of it so that people can tell you the real problem with the code.

Comment: For your second problem, `strncpy(test_st.fp.fing_print,token,31); test_st.fp.fing_print[31] = 0;`.

Comment: @Daniel - Since the example data has 32 char strings in the last field, I think that the `fing_print` field is actually not supposed to be null terminated - the OP might really want `strncpy(test_st.fp.fing_print, token, sizeof(test_st.fp.fing_print))`.  But only the OP can really answer which is wanted.

Comment: @John: the question about copying the last field data should probably be a separate question (since it has nothing to do with `strtok()`), and you should make clear whether the `fing_print` array is intended to be null terminated or not.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Okay, I didn't count;) Then it would be 32 or `sizeof` of course.

Comment: @michael burr: please check edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by paulsm4 you need to check `strtok()` return value. The following code works and includes the creation of the string:

```
while( fgets (buf , 100 , rd) != NULL )
{
    token = strtok(buf,", \n");
    if (0 != token)
    {
        test_st.fp.chunk_offset = atol(token); 
        printf("\tchunk_offset=%lu\n", test_st.fp.chunk_offset); 

        token = strtok(0, ", \n");
    }

    if (0 != token)
    {
        test_st.fp.chunk_length = atol(token);
        printf("\tchunk_length=%lu\n", test_st.fp.chunk_length);  
        token = strtok(0, ", \n");
    }

    if (0 != token)
    {
        /* EDIT: fing_print datatype changed. */
        memset(test_st.fp.fing_print, 0, sizeof(test_st.fp.fing_print));
        strncpy(test_st.fp.fing_print,
                token,
                sizeof(test_st.fp.fing_print) - 1);

        /* test_st.fp.fing_print = _strdup(token); */

        printf("\tfing_print=[%s]\n", test_st.fp.fing_print);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Delimiter set is `", \n"` as `fgets()` will read the newline character into `buf`.

Comment: the last  assignment gives this error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue.  in the line:  test_st.fp.fing_print = _strdup(token); it flags "test_st" to be the error

Comment: The datatype of `fing_print` has changed from `char*` to `char[32]`. If you change it back this code will be fine but I will edit the answer for this datatype change.

Comment: thank you hmjd. Is there a way to make it ignore the empty lines? I have very large files with empty lines in-between the lines containing the data. or should i re-generate it with out the empty lines?

Comment: here is what i did: strncpy((char*)test_st.fp.fing_print,token,32);

Comment: Before performing any `strtok()` you could check `if ('\n' != buf[0])` then the line is not empty and it should be parsed.

Comment: With that `strncpy()` the `fing_print` will will not be null terminated if the length of `token` is 32 characters. If you require it to be null terminated then `fing_print[33]`.

Comment: Some functions require that a string be null terminated, `strcmp()` for example. If you wanted to compare two `fing_print`s that were not null terminated then you could not use `strcmp()`, but could use `memcmp()` which requires that you specify the number of bytes to compare. `printf("%s")` requires that the string is null terminated, but you can use `printf("%.*s", 32, fing_print);` to print the first 32 bytes. If it is not null terminated it reduces the number of functions that you can use with them, but this may not be an issue for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! can you also please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862386/is-it-possible-to-bit-mask-a-char-array) problem of mine.

Comment: Afraid I can't help with that other problem John, I just don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for NULL return:

```
  if ((token = strtok(buf, ",")) {
    // must have found a comma
  }
  if (token && (token = strtok(NULL,"'")) {
    // Two in a row: I found a comma and then I found an apostrophe
  }
  ...
```